# Command-line tool for SQLite 2.1?

Tags: sqlite, command-line, sqlite2

Are there any command-line tools specifically for SQLite 2.1.

Comment: Any reason you can't use sqlite3-based tools, like everyone else?

Comment: I've got a corrupted database in SQLite 2.1 format. Hoped that command-line tool would help me to get data from it.

Answer (score 4):

You can download a version for 2.8 that will read it from the [wayback machine](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20031203050807/http://sqlite.org/download.html)